# Как из Java-приложения выполнить команду в CMD (системной консоли)?

Tags: java, cmd

Нужно из программы выполнить команду.

Например, нужно скопировать файл `copy C:\file.txt \\server`. Или это возможно только вызовом внешнего `batch` файла?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Tfads
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            //здесь "sleep 15" и есть ваша консольная команда
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sleep 15"); 
            proc.waitFor();
            proc.destroy();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Взято [отсюда](https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/development/9496282#comment-9496840).

Документация по Runtime [здесь](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html).

Comment: Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, Не удается найти указанный файл
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
        ... 5 more

Comment: Написал `Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("copy D:\\test112.txt \\\\192.168.36.26\\export"); `

Comment: @Евгений попробуйте посмотреть тут: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157303/how-to-execute-cmd-commands-via-java/5437863#5437863

Comment: А вообще путь не находило потому что пробелы в имени файла. Нужно было путь обернуть в кавычки и запускать `cmd /c copy...`.